# How to install ROS(Kinetic) in Mac OS Sierra?

Tags: python, macos, yaml, ros

My macbook pro system info:

- **macOS High Sierra**
- **Version 10.13.4**

And, I'm trying to following the [Office Guidings](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) to install *ros-kinetic-distro* version in my macbook. However, it's all good until come to the ***initialize-rosdep*** step:

```
$ sudo -H rosdep init
$ rosdep update
```

Here are the problems:

> ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
>   Website may be down.

So I have to go to the website-page find the ***suggestions*** like this:

```
# os-specific listings first
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx

# generic
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
gbpdistro https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml fuerte

# newer distributions (Groovy, Hydro, ...) must not be listed anymore, they are being fetched from the rosdistro index.yaml instead
```

I'm not familiar with ***yaml***, so I can't make it clear what the ***suggestions*** real meanings. And next, I have to install ***yaml***, unfortunately, there're comes another pieces of problems!

So I had installed **PyYAML** which seems located here:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages

with file ***PyYAML-3.12-py3.6.egg-info***.

But failed when I export the ***PATH*** into my *.zhsrc*:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages:$PATH
```

> yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx
>   zsh: permission denied: yaml
>
> sudo yaml
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx
>
> Password:
>
> sudo: yaml: command not found

So, What should I do to config the *yaml-command* in a right way? And, finally is there anyone make is success to install the ROS in MacBook? I really need your help!

Comment: yaml in a sources list file probably doesn't refer to a "yaml" application, but to the file format in the URL after it.

Comment: @StefanL Thanks anyway! So, do you have a good idea to config the ***yaml*** command in MacOS (with .bashrc or .zshrc)? As you know I'm confused with that whether it's a right way or not for me to install the ***PyYAML***, and set the command in my system!

Comment: I don't even have any "yaml" command installed on my system, don't think it'll contribute to installing ROS?

Comment: @StefanL So, Do you know the website-page suggestions meanings (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list) ?

Comment: looks like it's a ROS-specific file format, but appears to me to be inspired by Debian's sources.list format: https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

Comment: @StefanL OK，I got it! Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Suggestions" is irrelevant. What's happening is that it's trying to access a website to pull data from a file and that website is failing a certificate validation process on your machine.

A lot of suggestions hint at updating your certificates, but so far, none of that seems to help me.

From https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/9721: 
"I got the same error and fixed it by updating and upgrading the system"

Also:
"To solve the error I installed 'ca-certificates' package

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Then it worked for me"

Comment: openssl ca-certificates? Or just install the 'ca-certificates package' on my macos?

Comment: Thanks @Caleb Kuester & Shobi P P a lot. For the ***rosdep init*** problem, I had solved it with **j7nn7k** answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684543/how-to-make-python-use-ca-certificates-from-mac-os-truststore/42107877. Which just help me get through the ***init-step***, although there're a lot of problems after this step to install ros on my macos. Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There is now an easy way of installing ROS on OSX using conda: `conda install ros-noetic-desktop -c robostack`. More info on https://medium.com/robostack/cross-platform-conda-packages-for-ros-fa1974fd1de3 and https://github.com/RoboStack/ros-noetic

Comment: Note that this will require first installing [Anaconda Python](https://www.anaconda.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Here are my notes for Kinetic and High Sierra (partial success only though, ran out of patience): https://gist.github.com/stela/aba2fbd1d4adc8aa922af29c057f7b86

Another guide for Lunar on Sierra:
https://gist.github.com/lubiluk/361a018b267ca4e3ce10cdc68b17363d

The official Kinetic on (unspecified release of) OS X:
http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source

It's probably much easier to use the docker distribution though on a non-Linux OS.