# Why can't I use apt-get on Mac even though wget is installed

Tags: macos, wget, apt-get

I use Mac Big Sur 11.5.1. I installed `wget` using brew, but the terminal said `apt-get: command not found` when I put `sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-imu-tools`. Although I tried `brew install wget` again, it said `wget 1.21.1 is already installed and up-to-date`. So wget is installed for sure. What is a possible cause?

Comment: As this is not a programming question within the scope defined by the help center, it is off topic for Stack Overflow. For general operating system or application support, you may be able to find help on [su] or [apple.se], but be sure to follow their content guidelines to ensure an on-topic question.

Comment: ``apt`` has nothing to do with mac, where did you find this command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOS doesn't use apt as its package manager. Homebrew is the most popular package manager for macOS. Additionally, [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) is a separate software package than the package manager, [apt](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt). See the awesome answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688424/why-is-the-apt-get-function-not-working-in-the-terminal-on-mac-os-x-v10-9-maver) for more information.

I would try [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=rosdep+mac) search for getting it ROS working with Mac. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060718/how-to-install-roskinetic-in-mac-os-sierra) SO question might be of relevance too.