# How can I connect to MongoDB Atlas through Python 3.6 on my Macbook Air without SSL handshake error?

Tags: mongodb, macos, ssl, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I've set up a test MongoDb Atlas account, just one of the free ones and using the below code on my Ubuntu box I can successfully create users and also search for them.

When I try the exact same thing on my MacBook Air I get an SSL handshake as below.

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833),SSL handshake failed: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833),SSL handshake failed: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@cluster0-ABCDEF.mongodb.net/test")
db = client.johnny
collection = db.myjohnnytest

example = {'name' : 'Johnny',
            'email' : 'johnny@test.net'}

user_id = collection.insert_one(example).inserted_id
```

I found this answer which seemed like it was the key:

[Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098126/mac-osx-python-ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify)

But I have since tried this and whether I follow it exactly or activate my virtualenv I get the following error:

> Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 44, in 
>     File "", line 25, in main
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
>       raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
>   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6', '-E', '-s', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'certifi']' returned non-zero exit status 3.
>   logout
>   Saving session...
>   ...copying shared history...
>   ...saving history...truncating history files...
>   ...completed.

Comment: Have you installed third party dependancies for SSL secure connection on with pymango? `python -m pip install pymongo[tls]`

Answer (score 16):

By default, PyMongo is configured to require a certificate from the server when TLS is enabled. This is configurable using the ssl_cert_reqs option. To disable this requirement pass ssl.CERT_NONE as a keyword parameter:

```
>>> uri = 'mongodb://example.com/?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE'
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you update the CA bundle for Python?

From a bash shell/ terminal:
open "/Applications/Python 3.6/Install Certificates.command"

or Python 3.7 etc

[MongoDB Documentation for Python](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#python-driver-example)
[Stackoverflow article on MacOS, Python and CA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684543/how-to-make-python-use-ca-certificates-from-mac-os-truststore)

Comment: When you have enough rep, make this a comment please.

Answer (score 0):

I am showing 2 ways of solving this:

1. (easiest)

Adding `...&ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=/path/to/cert.pem` to the mongodb url

2. (recommended)

Configuring python SSL connection.

```
$ python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/etc/openssl/cert.pem', capath=None, openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/etc/openssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/etc/openssl/certs')
```

Then make sure you add your `cert.pem` file to the specified path. In my case, I should add it to the folder `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/etc/openssl/`