# Certificate verification fails on MacOs

Tags: python, django, macos, ssl, localhost

I'm attempting to do an esearch of the BioPython database using Django 2.1 and Python 3.7 but I seem to be getting an odd SSL Error I never got with earlier versions of Python/Django (i'm on a Mac)

I've install certifi but nothing seems to have happened.

```
        def results(request):
            disease = request.GET.get('disease_name')
            year_beginning = request.GET.get('year_beginning')
            year_ending = request.GET.get('year_ending')
            Entrez.email = "test@gmail.com"
            handle = Entrez.esearch(
                db="pubmed",
                sort="relevance",
                term=disease,
                mindate=year_beginning,
                maxdate=year_ending,
                retmode="xml",
            )
            results = Entrez.read(handle, validate="False")
            handle.close()
            print(results)
            context = {
                'results': results,
                }
            return render(request, 'lm_test/results.html', context)
```

This should return results similar to https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=xml&retmax=20&sort=relevance&term=fever but I just seem to be constantly getting an ssl error in my local host?

```
Error is: urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)
```

Answer (score 2):

So if anyone else has this issue:

Python 3.7 and Mac do not use the default SSL certificates anymore. Please follow this guide to fix your issue [How to make Python use CA certificates from Mac OS TrustStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684543/how-to-make-python-use-ca-certificates-from-mac-os-truststore)

Comment: This does not seem a problem with python but with the MacOS package. The `ssl` module does not mention anything about a bundled openssl.