# How to fix following ansible galaxy SSL error?

Tags: ssl, ansible, ubuntu-18.04, ansible-galaxy

Started learning Ansible and want to facilitate `ansible-galaxy search nginx` command, but I'm getting:

```
ERROR! Unknown error when attempting to call Galaxy at 'https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/api': <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)>
```

Had try to use `ansible-galaxy --ignore-certs search nginx` and `ansible-galaxy -c search nginx` but now getting `ansible-galaxy: error: unrecognized arguments: --ignore-certs` for booth.

OS :

> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
> Release:        18.04
> Codename:       bionic

Ansible version:

```
ansible 2.9.5
  config file = /home/maciej/projects/priv/ansible_nauka/packt_course/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/maciej/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/maciej/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/maciej/.local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27) [GCC 8.4.0]
```

Comment: Are you behind a web proxy ?

Comment: no I'm not behind proxy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had back to this issue... life is best motivator. What helped me is:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
```

Answer (score 26):

I had the same issue, but on Mac OS X.

The underlying problem is that your Python environment is not finding/making use of the default root certificates that are installed on your OS. These root certs are required to connect securely (via TLS) with Ansible Galaxy.

**For Mac OS X** I was able to solve this based on this answer:
[How to make Python use CA certificates from Mac OS TrustStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684543/how-to-make-python-use-ca-certificates-from-mac-os-truststore)

i.e. by running the script to install the certs, shipped with the installation:

```
cd /Applications/Python\ 3.7/
./Install\ Certificates.command
```

(your Python version might be different)

**For Ubuntu / Debian**:

Update: As pointed out by Maciej in the accepted answer, certs can be regenerated and added to the environment:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
```

**P.S.**: I would not suggest to use `--ignore-certs`, this will skip verification of the certificate in the TLS connection, making the connection insecure (allowing [Man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack))

Comment: the python version number will probably be different. I had to use `cd /Applications/Python\ 3.10/`.

Comment: thank you for the hint, I added a remark

Comment: There is another answer to the same reply that is more consistent, since it works for Python versions installed with pyenv/brew/...: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57795811/384617

Answer (score 7):

Worked for me:

```
ansible-galaxy search --ignore-certs postgresql
```

Answer (score 3):

in case someone else is looking at this, the args are order dependent. On rhel8 with a cntlm proxy ....

```
declare -x https_proxy='127.0.0.1:3128'
declare -x http_proxy='127.0.0.1:3128'

# this works through a proxy
ansible-galaxy collection install ovirt.ovirt --ignore-certs

# this does not
ansible-galaxy --ignore-certs collection install ovirt.ovirt 

# and this does not
ansible-galaxy collection --ignore-certs install ovirt.ovirt
```

Comment: `--ignore-certs` or `-c` works for me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**For RHEL/CENTOS**

You may want to check the cryptopolicy, if the policy is set to future temporarily set it to default

`sudo update-crypto-policies --set=DEFAULT`