# Cannot install chromedriver-binary

Tags: python, pip, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to execute a requirement.txt file using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Among the requirements that are in this file, there is also `chromedriver-binary==99.0.4844.51.0`.

I get the following error when executing the script:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: chromedriver-binary
  Building wheel for chromedriver-binary (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [86 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      
      Downloading Chromedriver...
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in do_open
          h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
          self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
          self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
          self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
          self.send(msg)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 950, in send
          self.connect()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1424, in connect
          self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
          return self.sslsocket_class._create(
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
          self.do_handshake()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
          self._sslobj.do_handshake()
      ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/folders/cn/z0bwy5817r75b0x34py5qtzw0000gn/T/pip-install-wpqkdi4m/chromedriver-binary_29a0181dd63c4ff583dcd2e906683a82/setup.py", line 44, in run
          response = urlopen(url)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
          return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
          response = self._open(req, data)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
          result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
          result = func(*args)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1389, in https_open
          return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1349, in do_open
          raise URLError(err)
      urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)>
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/cn/z0bwy5817r75b0x34py5qtzw0000gn/T/pip-install-wpqkdi4m/chromedriver-binary_29a0181dd63c4ff583dcd2e906683a82/setup.py", line 59, in <module>
          setup(
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/cn/z0bwy5817r75b0x34py5qtzw0000gn/T/pip-install-wpqkdi4m/chromedriver-binary_29a0181dd63c4ff583dcd2e906683a82/setup.py", line 48, in run
          raise RuntimeError('Failed to download chromedriver archive: {}'.format(url))
      RuntimeError: Failed to download chromedriver archive: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/chromedriver_mac64.zip
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for chromedriver-binary
  Running setup.py clean for chromedriver-binary
Failed to build chromedriver-binary
Installing collected packages: chromedriver-binary
  Running setup.py install for chromedriver-binary ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for chromedriver-binary did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [90 lines of output]
      running install
      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      
      Downloading Chromedriver...
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in do_open
          h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
          self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
          self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
          self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
          self.send(msg)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 950, in send
          self.connect()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1424, in connect
          self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
          return self.sslsocket_class._create(
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
          self.do_handshake()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
          self._sslobj.do_handshake()
      ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/folders/cn/z0bwy5817r75b0x34py5qtzw0000gn/T/pip-install-wpqkdi4m/chromedriver-binary_29a0181dd63c4ff583dcd2e906683a82/setup.py", line 44, in run
          response = urlopen(url)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
          return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
          response = self._open(req, data)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
          result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
          result = func(*args)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1389, in https_open
          return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1349, in do_open
          raise URLError(err)
      urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)>
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/cn/z0bwy5817r75b0x34py5qtzw0000gn/T/pip-install-wpqkdi4m/chromedriver-binary_29a0181dd63c4ff583dcd2e906683a82/setup.py", line 59, in <module>
          setup(
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 68, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/install.py", line 670, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/cn/z0bwy5817r75b0x34py5qtzw0000gn/T/pip-install-wpqkdi4m/chromedriver-binary_29a0181dd63c4ff583dcd2e906683a82/setup.py", line 48, in run
          raise RuntimeError('Failed to download chromedriver archive: {}'.format(url))
      RuntimeError: Failed to download chromedriver archive: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/99.0.4844.51/chromedriver_mac64.zip
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> chromedriver-binary

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I tried everything in order to install chromedriver-binary by myself (from https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-py/), but with no success. I am using macOS.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

Solved issue by executing:

```
CERT_PATH=$(python -m certifi)
export SSL_CERT_FILE=${CERT_PATH}
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=${CERT_PATH}
```

See: [How to make Python use CA certificates from Mac OS TrustStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684543/how-to-make-python-use-ca-certificates-from-mac-os-truststore/42107877#42107877)