# Can not connect dbt cloud or dbt core to databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, dbt, databricks-connect

I am having issue connecting my dbt cloud and dbt core to databricks

I have read these 4 links, but still can not connect

https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/prep/dbt-cloud.html#connect-to-dbt-cloud&language-Cluster

https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/prep/dbt.html

https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/warehouse-profiles/databricks-profile

https://github.com/databricks/dbt-databricks

on dbt-cloud:

When I test the connection during the project creation step, it passed the test. however when I use the connection to create a job and run, it returns this message:"Cannot set database in spark!"

Edit: the issue once has been fixed but it comes back again.

original fix:
The dbt-core connection issue has been fixed. The issue is caused by the python certificate issue on MacOS. please refer to this link for the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684543/how-to-make-python-use-ca-certificates-from-mac-os-truststore)

on dbt-core:
this how I set up my profiles.yaml file base on the documentations:

```
    databrick_dbt_lakehouse:
      outputs:
        dev:
          host: adb-755xxxxxxx7.7.azuredatabricks.net
          http_path: /sql/protocolv1/o/755xxxx7/0517-xxxxxx-xxxxxx
          schema: default
          threads: 1
          token: dapi<my token>
          type: databricks
      target: dev
```

Note:

1. for http_path i have tried both with or without backslash (/) before sql/...
2. I assume the schema means database name. I have tried 2, but none of them works
3. I use pipenv with python version 3.8.8

when I run `dbt debug` I got this message:

```
check failed:
   dbt was unable to connect to the specified database.
   The database returned the following error:

Runtime Error
   Database Error
   failed to connect
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: http_path seems to be different.  I see /sql/1.0/endpoints/......  in all my endpoints.

Comment: are you using sql endpoint or generic cluster?

Comment: dbt-core connection fixed by install python certification on my MacBook

Comment: was the issue resolved by a change to the `profiles.yml`? or by installing the `certification` library?

Comment: solved by installing the certification library

Comment: @AndersSwanson this issue came back to me again.

Answer (score 1):

Your `http_path` seems wrong. Here is an extract from my `profiles.yml`

```
databricks_dbt_demo:
  outputs:
    dev:
      host: adb-redacted.azuredatabricks.net

      http_path: /sql/1.0/endpoints/redacted  # for SQL Endpoint
      # http_path: /sql/protocolv1/o/{ORG-ID}/{CLUSTER-ID}  # for All-Purpose Cluster
      schema: your_database_here
      token: your_personal_access_token_here
      type: databricks
  target: dev
```

Are you using a cluster (e.g. All Purpose Cluster) or a SQL Endpoint?

Comment: I am using all propose cluster. your path looks like a sql endpoint. on their documentation it should support both.

Comment: @JulianEccleshall if you're using an all-purpose cluster, `/sql/protocolv1/o/{ORG-ID}/{CLUSTER-ID}`

Comment: yes, this is the setup in my profile

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This issue is came back again. I am writing this comment on the 3rd day after the original fix

When I run `dbt run` or `dbt snapshot` the returns this error message:

```
Encountered an error:
Runtime Error
   Database Error
      failed to connect
```

original fix:

The issue is caused by the python certificate issue on MacOS. please refer to this link for the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684543/how-to-make-python-use-ca-certificates-from-mac-os-truststore).

The dbt cloud issue is caused by the incorrect schema name in the yaml file