# Error connecting dbt-core to Azure Databricks Cluster

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, dbt

Have tried different azure Databricks clusters for dbt connection but all tries produced same error message,
python version# 3.8.13, dbt version# 1.4.5, here a scree hot with error message:

[image]

have tried creating few Azure Databricks Workspaces/ different clusters but no luck, same error .

Comment: Checkout this issue which addressing similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72291367/can-not-connect-dbt-cloud-or-dbt-core-to-databricks

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP perhaps because of using proxy, as reading @ https://github.com/databricks/dbt-databricks/issues/111

Comment: when i debug,  the NoneType error was triggered because port-number is null, passing the  port-number in the host name doesn't help either