# HTTP request fails in Flask request, succeeds from command line

Tags: python, flask, ssl, python-requests, gunicorn

In trying to write a flask app, I ran into a problem making an outbound HTTP call using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) to an API while processing the request. If I run the same function from the python command line, it works. **Why?**

**Update** If I add gunicorn and make the call to flask via gunicorn, it works!

I've simplified my flask app and I get the same error.

```py
import requests
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    try:
        response = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
        data = response.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Caught exception {e}")
        data = "no data: error"
    return(f'<pre>{data}</pre>')
```

Saved as `sslerror.py`, requires installing `flask` and `requests`.

**Web Request**

I run the flask app using `flask --app sslerror run`. Flask listens at `http://127.0.0.1:5000`. When I visit that in my browser, I get this error:

```
Caught exception HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /get (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(0, 'unknown error (_ssl.c:3098)')))`
```

**Python REPL**

From the command line, on the other hand:

```py
>>> from sslerror import hello_world
>>> hello_world()
"<pre>{'args': {}, 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.31.0', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-652f409a-abcdefabcdef'}, 'origin': '108.x.x.x', 'url': 'https://httpbin.org/get'}</pre>"
```

**Adding Gunicorn**

```bash
$ pip install gunicorn
$ gunicorn -w 1 sslerror:app
```

Gunicorn listens at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. When I visit that, I see results in my browser

Environment info: MacOS 13.6 (Ventura) on Apple m2 chip. I'm using python 3.11.5 from [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

I've also tried adding `verify=False` and `allow_redirects=False` to the `get()` call. The result was the same each time.

**WHY** does the outbound HTTP request work from the command line but not in the context of the flask request?

*Update:* I also tried in new virtualenvs with python 3.8 (from pyenv) and 3.11 from homebrew. Same behavior.

*Update 2:* I added gunicorn and it works?!

*Update 3:* I tried swapping out requests and using [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/). Breaks the same way. This is smelling like a flask issue.

Comment: I did run this in my machine with Macos and M2 chip and it's working fine for me.

Comment: Can you show how you used the verify=False? I just tried it and it works for me without errors.

Comment: @hikerjobs I used `requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get", verify=False)`

Thank you and thank you, @AbdulNiyasPM, for testing. Are you both also using python from pyenv?

Comment: Yes, I am. Python 3.11 using venv. MacOS 13.6. But for me, verify=False works. The other alternative is to try and install the certificates and/or point to where they are installed and see if that helps resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution ***that works sometimes*** thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57795811/138776) to a different Stack Overflow question:

```bash
CERT_PATH=$(python -m certifi)
export SSL_CERT_FILE=${CERT_PATH}
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=${CERT_PATH}
```

(Although I do not understand why I got different behavior in flask vs REPL)